How can i hide a particular column in a Kendo React Grid?
I have a kendo react grid and the columns are defined as
              <Grid                       
                    <Column field="name" title="Name" />
                    <Column field="uId" title="UId" />
                 </Grid>

Is there a flag i can put on here so as to hide the "uId" column ?
